# Multirow cells with lines aligning vertically with text in each row

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularray

Is it possible to achieve a table that looks like the one in the image below without manually dividing the row headings as I have done in my code?

[image: Desired result]

To be explicit, what I am after is the following.

1. Table width is set to `\linewidth`. (I have used `tabularx` to achieve this.)
2. The vertical space between table cells is increased (I have used `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}`.)
3. The row headings (in column 1) automatically wrap when they are too long. (I have faked this manually.)
4. The lines of the row headings should align with the numbers in the table body. (I have faked this by manually dividing the row headings and inputting the parts on different rows.)
5. The wrapped row headings should have a hanging indent. (I have faked this manually by adding `\hspace{1em}`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[ht]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}  % Exaggregated for the sake of clarity
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X *{4}{c} @{}}
      \toprule
                                                              &   A   &   B   &   C   &   D   \\
      \midrule
      The first row heading runs over one line                &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\
                                                              & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\
      [1em]
      The third row heading is slightly longer and            &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\
      \hspace{1em} runs over two lines                        & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\
      [1em]
      The third row heading is actually quite                 &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\
      \hspace{1em} outrageously long and runs over a total of & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\
      \hspace{1em} three lines \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Sorry, desired table design is not very clear to me ..
- So below are three my guessing ...

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={@{}  X[l, cmd=\hangindent 1em\hangafter 1] 
                          *{4}{c} @{}},
                 cell{odd}{1} = {r=2}{},
                 rowsep=1ex,
                 vspan = even,
                }
The first row heading runs over one lin                                                       
    &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\ 
    & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\ 
The second row heading is slightly longer and runs over two lines
    &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\
    & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\ 
The third row heading is actually quite outrageously long and runs over a total of three lines 
    &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\
    & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\ 
    \end{tblr}
  \end{table}
  
\noindent
or

  \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={@{}  X[l, cmd=\hangindent 1em\hangafter 1]
                          *{4}{c} @{}},
                 cell{odd}{1} = {r=2}{},
                 row{odd[3]} = {abovesep=2ex},
                 vspan = even,
                }
The first row heading runs over one lin
    &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\
    & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\
The second row heading is slightly longer and runs over two lines
    &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\
    & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\
The third row heading is actually quite outrageously long and runs over a total of three lines
    &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\
    & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\
    \end{tblr}
  \end{table}

\noindent
or

  \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={@{}  X[l, cmd=\hangindent 1em\hangafter 1]
                          *{4}{c} @{}},
                 cell{odd}{1} = {r=2}{},
                 rowsep = 1pt,
                 row{odd[3]} = {abovesep=2ex},
                }
The first row heading runs over one lin
    &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\
    & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\
The second row heading is slightly longer and runs over two lines
    &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\
    & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\
The third row heading is actually quite outrageously long and runs over a total of three lines
    &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\
    & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\
    \end{tblr}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show text block borders)

**Addendum:**
now I guessing that you after something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={@{}  X[l, h, cmd=\hangindent 1em\hangafter 1]
                          *{4}{Q[c, h]} @{}},
                 cell{odd}{1} = {r=2}{},
                    rowsep    = 1pt,
                 row{odd[3]}  = {abovesep=2ex},
%                        vspan = even,
                }
The first row heading runs over one lin
    &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\
    & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\
The second row heading is slightly longer and runs over two lines
    &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\
    & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\
The third row heading is actually quite outrageously long and runs over a total of three lines
    &  123  &  123  &  123  &  123  \\
    & (456) & (456) & (456) & (456) \\
    \end{tblr}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly, none of these are what I intended :-( None of them have the row headings' first line aligned with the first line of figures in the table body. And none of them have the row headings' second line aligned with the corresponding second line of figures in the table body.

Comment: But the indent is just what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @FredrikP Where exactly Zarko failed with this answer? Do you expects line spread to be equivalent in all columns; as such, the spacing between subsequent lines in the first column would match spacing between quantities and uncertainties and the first column would still continue adding more lines when necessary. This is still a guess because I can't find it explained.

Comment: @Zarko I have made an attempt to clarify what I am after.

Comment: @Celdor That is exactly what I am after :-) I have tried to clarify in an edit of the question.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for bearing with me. I agree that all of your cases solve points 1-3 and 5. But neither of them solve point 4. None of the first row heading lines align vertically with the 123 line, none of the second row heading lines align vertically with the (456) line, and none of the third row heading lines align vertically with where a hypothetical 789 line would be. Can you see it?

Comment: @Zarko I can’t think of how I can myself clearer. Maybe I will see things differently tomorrow. FWIW, I have provided a sketch for what I am after. It is the image in the question. The sought-after solution would look **exactly** like that. But the markup should look much more like your three cases.

Comment: @FredrikP, see addendum to answer

Comment: @Zarko Again, thank you for bearing with me! We are getting closer! Now, the first lines of the row headings are vertically aligned with the 123 rows. But the second lines of the row headings are still not aligned with the (456) rows. This becomes apparent if you do not decrease `rowsep` from `1ex` to `1pt` as you did in your addendum. I have posted [a new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683314/automatically-expand-height-of-multirow-cells-second-row-to-fit-content) that I hope will be clearer.

Comment: @Celdor [New attempt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683314/automatically-expand-height-of-multirow-cells-second-row-to-fit-content)