# Replicate tabulary's L column with tabularray

Tags: tabularray, tabulary

I get the impression that you can [replicate the behavior of `tabulary`'s `L` column using `tabularray`](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/discussions/397#discussioncomment-5669820) but I can't get it to work. What I am after is a column that is typeset with its natural width as long as the table's natural width is below some threshold (here, `\linewidth`) but, as long as the table's natural width exceeds the threshold, contracts to ensure that the table's actual width equals the threshold.

In my example, I have posted four tables:

- two made with `tabulary` and
- two made with `tabularray`.

Each pair of tables takes two forms:

- one where the first cell contains a short text (to ensure that the table's natural width is less than `\linewidth`) and
- one where the first cell contains a long text (to ensure that the table's natural width exceeds `\linewidth`).

What I am after is a common column specification for the `tabularray` tables that makes them behave as the `tabulary` tables.

[image: tabulary tables]

[image: tabularray tables]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
  \section*{\texttt{tabulary}}
  \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{} L *{4}{c} @{}}
      \hline
      The text in this cell can be short & A & B & C & D \\
      \hline
    \end{tabulary}
  \end{table}

  \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{} L *{4}{c} @{}}
      \hline
      But it can also be really, really, really, really long. So long in fact the line needs to wrap in order to make room for it & A & B & C & D \\
      \hline
    \end{tabulary}
  \end{table}

  \newpage

  \section*{\texttt{tabularray}}
  \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={@{}X[-1,l,h,]*{4}{Q[c, h]}@{}},
    }
      \hline
      The text in this cell can be short & A & B & C & D \\
      \hline
    \end{tblr}
  \end{table}

  \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={@{}X[-1,l,h,]*{4}{Q[c, h]}@{}},
    }
      \hline
      But it can also be really, really, really, really long. So long in fact the line needs to wrap in order to make room for it & A & B & C & D \\
      \hline
    \end{tblr}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: currently `tabularray` cannot do dynamic width. if the width is not specified it will assume `\linewidth` when `X` columns are used and will not shrink if it is not required. It is quite annoying but has been reported already (see https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/97). Even `nicematrix` doesn't quite behave satisfactorily for this.

Comment: @ArTourter That was frustrating. I was beginning to hope that I had found One Ring to rule them all.

Comment: see you can't get rid of me just yet:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Haha! I really, really like `tabulary`. It is just frustrating when I find [things that can’t seem to be done using the standard tools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/683314/71332). And whereas `tabularx` and `tabulary` play nice with `threeparttable` and `booktabs`, `tabularray` does not, which leads to a lot of work trying to make tables look consistent. Work that I really would prefer to avoid.